# Is there a standard way to get an ActiveRecord item within Ruby on Rails from a given URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a standard way to get an ActiveRecord item in Ruby on Rails from a given URL?
I have some data in an external RDF database which I can query to get URLs for items in my Ruby on Rails code. I then want to get hold of the ActiveRecord objects belonging to these URLs inside my Ruby on Rails program. 
An example of the query results from the database:

```
"http://localhost:3000/data_files/5",
"http://localhost:3000/assays/3", 
"http://localhost:3000/assays/5"
```

I know that I could parse this and call:

```
DataFile.find(5)
Assays.find(3)
Assays.find(5)
```

but I thought there might be a standard bit of code that does this. 
As you can see I could have multiple types of object to search for, and so I need to get the right object type as well as using the id number.

Comment: best solution is to user ActiveResource::Base class

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: ActiveResource is longer part of Rails. The version you've linked to is from five years ago.

Comment: @AndyWaite thanks for notifying that. https://github.com/rails/activeresource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your basic example something like this should work.

```
def get_object_from_url url_string
  class_string = url_string.split('/')[-2]
  object_id = url_string.split('/')[-1]

  class_string.camelize.constantize.find_by_id(object_id)
end
```

Would require more complicated logic depending on the url's.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer - I didn't know how to do the final line of code. I had expected there to be a method like `ActionRecord.find(url)` but it looks like there isn't.

Comment: I also needed to `singularise` the class_string, like this: `class_string.singularize.camelize.constantize.find_by_id(object_id)`